# Autolayout on a sub view prevents the whole window from being resized

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

I have a simple view with a few labels, textfields and a big **NSTextField** that spans across the remaining interface.

I can setup auto layout so that the text field spans over the width of the window, but as soon as I add the last contraint **Bottom space to container** to its super view the window can no longer be resized.

These are my constraints:

[image: constraints]

So currently I have to omit this constraint and I end up with the following result:

See Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to fiddle with priorities on the constraints. Especially consider doing this on the height constraint.

Comment: But I set the height to "Greater than ..." so this should not be contradictive to changing the window's height.